# Totally Krossed Out

Tags: phrase-meaning

> **Totally Krossed Out** is the debut studio album by American hip hop duo Kris Kross. It was produced and largely written by Jermaine Dupri and released on March 31, 1992, by Ruffhouse Records and Columbia Records. After developing a musical concept for the duo, Dupri spent two years writing and producing the album.

Source: [Totally Krossed Out - Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Totally_Krossed_Out)

"Krossed Out" appears to use "Kross" (from the name Kris Kross) as a verb (playing with "cross"). What does "krossed out" mean? We know that "cross out" refers to "to draw a line through (something) to show that it is wrong." So I guess "totally krossed out" means "totally deleted." Now sure whether I am on the right track.

Comment: It could mean "eliminated from contention", as in "cross that idea out". Could also be a play on "grossed out". Regardless, it's a weak title, and we can only guess at its meaning.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are correct that "crossed out" *literally* refers to text (usually handwritten) that has been 'struck out' - a line put through it to show that it should be ignored because it is an error.

However, "Krossed Out" could also imply a different meaning. It is common to add the word "out" to something to show that it is all used up, or has reached some limit. For example, "tired out" means completely tired. Something that has reached its natural limit may be said to be "maxed out". But also, in colloquial speech, this construction is sometimes played with - for example, a person who has eaten too many burgers might say "I'm burgered out!" So "Krossed Out" possibly carries the meaning of being the most you could have from the band 'Kriss Kross'.

Comment: Album titles don't have to "mean" anything.

Comment: I always thought it was a play on "totally strung out".

Comment: @LawrenceC Maybe. Or totally *spaced* out, or *zoned* out... it could be anything. I think I've given the OP the means to make their own mind up.

Answer (score 0):

While an answer has been selected, I suggest that it may be wrong.

While "cross out" is a common term, "totally crossed out" is not (as far as I know).

However, the term "totally grossed out" is in fairly wide use, and I'd guess that this is the basis for the phrase. It makes for an eye-catching title, but has no literal connection.

Comment: At first I read "Kross" in my head as rhyming with "Gross" and also figured it was a pun on "grossed out". But looking at the [album art](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Totally_Krossed_Out#/media/File:Totally_Krossed_Out_album_coverart.jpg) convinced me otherwise.